# Split data equally for equal proportion of 0 and 1 in dependent variable

Tags: python

I have a dataset in which the dependent variable is 0 or 1. However, there are a huge number of 0s (10 times as much as 1s). I wanted to know what the fastest way is to create a subset in which the dependent variable proportions are equal?

Comment: My dataset is huge with 800000 rows and 20 independent variables along with the dependent variable

Comment: what do you mean by 800000 rows, is it a file or something ?

Comment: It's a dataframe, yes a file